# How to change the MaxRequestHeadersTotalSize in Azure Web App

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, iis

I have a web page hosted at Azure Web App using a long HTTP header (+50KB) and causes an error with the following message:

> The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server
>   terminated the process

My local development environment has the problem too, but I solved it by setting the `MaxRequestHeadersTotalSize` in the Krestel configuration of the `StartUp` class.

If I am not mistaken, Azure does not use Krestel as web server (I guess is IIS) and **I cannot find how to change the HTTP header size limit in Azure's server**.

The web page has been developed with ASP.NET Core 2.2.

Comment: Settings can be changed via a trick, https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/5703

Answer (score 1):

Add to your app web.config file and customize it and then deploy a project with this modified config to azure.